# How to read the UDTs from collection(for ex:list) of UDTs with cassandra-driver in java?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, user-defined-types

I have table `emp(id,name,list<frozen<address>>)`. Here address is cassandra UDT defined as `create TYPE address (hno int,street text);`. I am trying to read all address's for a given id in emp using below code and I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<'address'> <-> com.xyz.cassandra.address]

```
String query1="select * from iotbilling.emp where id=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement2=this.session.prepare(query1);
BoundStatement boundStatement2=preparedStatement2.bind(4);
ResultSet rs2=this.session.execute(boundStatement2);
Row row2=rs2.one();
List<address> addresses=row2.getList("adresses",address.class);
System.out.println("Addresses retrieved");
for(address adr:addresses)
    System.out.println(adr.toString());
```

`

Here, how to capture the list of frozen address in java code that is returned from cassandra?

Comment: General formating

Comment: Prior versions of the driver have had bugs around this feature.  Make sure you are running the most-recent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the value from row and read the metadata row by row:

```
UDTValue udtData = row.getUDTValue(address);
```

For example:

```
udtData.getString("name");
```

**Update with list example**

For a list it should probably look like:

```
List<UDTValue> udtDataList = row.getList("adresses", UDTValue.class)
```

And then you can easily iterate through the list and access the fields of your data.

Best

Comment: But, in my case, that is a collection(list) of frozen UDTs. How, can we get that list of address with your piece of code that is , UDTValue udtData = row.getUDTValue(address); ? Your code works well if i am storing only a single UDT instead of list<frozen<address>> . 
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks @questionare. But, your code should be re-written as List<UDTValue> udtDataList = row.getList("adresses",UDTValue.class);
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use datastax Mapper for this purpose. You have to declare your Java table and type Table using Datastax annotations like this:

```
    @Table(keyspace = "corporate", name = "emp")
     public class Employee{

          @PartitionKey(0)
          @Column(name = "id")
           private Integer id;

          @Column(name = "name")
           private String name;

          @Frozen
          @Column(name = "address_list")
          private List<Address> address;

          ...(Getter and Setters)
     }
```

And your UDT annotated as below:

```
     @UDT(keyspace = "corporate", name="address")
     public class Address{

          @Field(name="hno")
          private Integer hno;

          @Field(name="street")
          private String street;

          ...(Getters and Setters)
     }
```

You might want to add the following dependency to your pom.xml file beforehand if you haven't

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After these steps you need to use Mapper object to get your results:

```
    MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(this.session);
    Mapper<Employee> mapper = manager.mapper(Employee.class);
```

And once you get resultSet use mapper to get:

```
    Result<Employee> list = mapper.map(rs2);
    Employee emp = list.one();
```

Now you can access emp as java object and use emp.getAddress to access your list.