# How can I view the schema for my UDT in cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have created a `UDT` but I can't remember its definition now. Is there a command in `cqlsh` which I can use to list down all the UDTs and their definition?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DESCRIBE` command. To view the schema for your keyspace in cqlsh:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACE myks;
```

For details, see [cqlsh `DESCRIBE` command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshDescribe.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This will show all the UDTs in the current keyspace.

`cqlsh> desc types`

OR

`cqlsh> describe types`

To see schema of a particular type

`cqlsh> desc type <name of the UDT>`

OR

`cqlsh> describe type <name of the UDT>`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value row by row by using below:

```
UDTValue UdtData = row.getUDTValue(address);
UdtData.getString("Id");
```

Comment: That is not what i need.

Comment: how can I find the definition of the UDT using `cqlsh`?

Comment: @ManuChadha Did you follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589519/how-to-read-the-udts-from-collectionfor-exlist-of-udts-with-cassandra-driver